# Как добраться до ключей в массиве из объектов?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = new Array({
  "attr1": "text1",
  "attr2": "text2"
}, {
  "attr1": "text3",
  "attr2": "text4"
});
```

Тут два объекта, как мне добраться до ключей? Например, чтобы в консоль вывести все ключи и значения, как работать с таким массивом?

Comment: например console.log(a[0]['attr1']); выведет text1, а как мне через цикл прогнать все?

Comment: a = new Array(

          {"id":"1","text":"text1"},

          {"id":"2","text":"text2"}

          );

        $.each(a, function(index,value) {

          console.log(value['id']);
          
          });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проитерироваться по массиву можно с помощью цикла [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for (let object of a) {
    // тут что-то делаем с `object`
}
```

Получить все ключи или значения помогут методы [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) и [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). Оба этих метода возвращают массив, проитерироваться по которому, опять же, можно с помощью цикла `for...of`.

Например, вот так можно вывести ключи всех объектов массива:

```
for (let object of a) {
    let keys = Object.keys(object);
    for (let key of keys) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)